# covert a data frame to mldr object (second argument must be a list)

Tags: r, multilabel-classification

I want to convert my data frame to mldr object, I get this error: 
Error in do.call(paste, c(dataframe[, new_mldr$labels$index], sep = "")) : second argument must be a list

my data frame head is as follows:

```
 hour P    load    week_day days  month    lable
```

67   13   1    12274        3    3     1        13
72   18   1    13620        3    3     1        22
73   19   1    13988        3    3     1        22
74   20   1    13748        3    3     1        22
75   21   1    13306        3    3     1        22
87    7   1    11556        4    4     1        13

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you get this error when using the `mldr_from_dataframe` function, most probably because you are providing `labelIndices` with a single index (number 7 corresponding to your column called `lable`). Multi-label classification expects multiple labels and your problem seems to be a single-label classification one, in which case `mldr` is unneeded.